# How to check if there are 3 or 4 or 5 consecutive numbers in a list with 6 items?

Tags: python, list, numbers, items

How to check if there are 3 or 4 or 5 or 6 consecutive numbers in a list with 6 items?

I’m using `python`.
I tried to generate combinations of numbers 1-42. I have 5million+ combinations. I am trying to reduce the number of combinations by removing the ones that have 3-6 consecutive numbers.

Given lists:

```
(5,8,12,28,29,30) has 3 consecutive

(1,8,9,10,11,23) has 4 consecutive

(2,12,13,14,15,16) has 5 consecutive

(3,4,5,6,7,8) has 6 consecutive

(3,9,11,14,15,21) has 2 consecutive

(2,5,7,12,21,34)

(3,5,8,10,12,34)
```

By removing the lists that have 3-6 consecutive numbers the output should be:

```
(3,9,11,14,15,21)

(2,5,7,12,21,34)

(3,5,8,10,12,34)
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what you're asking for:

```
import itertools

def maxRunSize(t):
    return 1+max(len(tuple(g)) if k else 0 for k,g in itertools.groupby(zip(t, t[1:]), key=lambda t: t[1]-t[0]==1))
```

Output:

```
In [87]: maxRunSize((5,8,12,28,29,30))                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
Out[87]: 3

In [88]: maxRunSize((1,8,9,10,11,23))                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
Out[88]: 4

In [89]: maxRunSize((2,12,13,14,14,16))                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
Out[89]: 3

In [90]: maxRunSize((2,12,13,14,15,16))                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
Out[90]: 5

In [91]: maxRunSize((3,4,5,6,7,8))                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
Out[91]: 6
```

But if you'd rather just generate combinations without long runs (so that you won't have to filter them out later), check this out:

```
import random
def generate(n, k, window):
    """
    Generate n-choose-k combinations in [1,n] such that there is no window-length of consecutive numbers
    """

    answer = []
    while True:
        if len(answer) >= window:
            if answer[-window:] == list(range(answer[-window], window+1)):
                answer = []
            elif len(answer) == k:
                yield answer
                answer = []
        elif len(answer) == window-1:
            if answer[1-window:] == list(range(answer[1-window], window)):
                answer.append(random.choice([i for i in range(1,n+1) if i!=answer[-1]+1]))
        else:
            answer.append(random.choice(range(1,n+1)))
```

Comment: This seems to work. I’d just get the ones with 3-6 consecutive numbers then remove it. Output the remaining lists. Can you please explain the code? This is a new learning for me. Thank you so much.

Comment: The code generates and yields combinations of size `k` (6, in your case). However, as it generates a viable combination, it looks as the last `window-1` elements and checks if they form a valid run. If so, the next number it generates is still within the interval [1,n], but does not include the one number that would continue the run

Answer (score 0):

If all sequnces have exactly 6 numbers in strictly increasing order, you could use a quick and simple test:

```
if any(x[i]+2 == x[i+2] for i in range(4)):
    # ... remove x ...
```